# Get notified when added new property to window object - js

Tags: javascript, window, dom-events

I need to listen to some event (if it exists of course) to know when new property was added to `window` object. Is that possible?

For example:

I have a code in application that don't know what global variable some library exposes (e.g. underscore.js which exposes global `_` instead of `underscore`). I need to be notified that new property was assigned to `window`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways you could try to do that but neither is a great option.

1. You can check for changes to the `window` object using `setInterval`. This will be slow and there will be a delay between when a new property is added to `window` and when your code will notice it. Here is some code that shows **one** way of doing that: http://jsbin.com/vubew/1/edit?js,console

   ```
   (function(){
     'use strict';
     var keys = Object.keys(window).join();

     setInterval(function(){
       var newKeys = Object.keys(window).join();

       if (newKeys !== keys) {
         console.log('`window` changed');
         keys = newKeys;
       }
     }, 100);

   })();
   ```
2. You could use ES7's `Object.observe` method. Unfortunately, only Chrome supports it (behind an experimental flag) right now.

Once you determine there has been a change with one of these methods you'd generate an event that your code would be listening for.